# Calculating MD5 hashes of files in compressed zip archive

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate MD5 hashes of files contained in a zip archive.

For example, I have an zip file that contains three files: Prizes.dat, Promotions.dat and OutOfDate.dat and I would like to calculate the MD5 of the three files to compare it with a given string. Since I need to do this on a very very large amount of zip Archives, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this directly without decompressing the file.

Thanks in advance!

superPanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to calculate the MD5 hash of a zipped file and store it in the zip archive alongside the file. If you are generating these files yourself, you can just hash the file before you zip it. If you are receiving the ZIP files from somewhere else, then write a script that will automate going through all the files and adding hashes. Then whenever you need to check the hash in the program, you can just pull the precomputed hash from the ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Unfortunately, I'm receiving these files from my customers and I honestly don't know if they know what is an MD5 at all :). So, how could I do it? Maybe I can extract files in-memory? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could extract the files whenever they are submitted and then calculate the hashes. If you are receiving them directly (FTP, email, etc) then you could write a script and manually run it. If you are having them upload the files to a server, you could run a server side script that would do it.

Comment: Ok and, since I have a large amount of zip Archives to test, I could write a For Each instruction for each zip file, extract it, calculate MD5 hashes, delete temporary files and then pass to the next?

Comment: Sure, that should work. If you get a lot of traffic you might have to tweak things a little, but that is a basic pattern that will work.

Comment: Thanks casperw for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this need and discovered a way to check the hash of a file contained in a tarball without writing the uncompressed data to disk (unzipping).
BSD example below hence the `md5`

```
tar xOfz archive.tgz foo.txt | md5
tar xOfj archive.bz2 foo.txt | md5
```

Or use `tar xOfz archive.tgz foo.txt | md5sum`

for linux.